# Yii update DB fields on browser tab close

Tags: php, jquery, session, yii

In my Yii application i want to prevent same user simultaneous login.

**1. While user login i update DB field logged_in as 1.So, if same user login again i check this field (logged_in) and if its 1 then throw 'user already connected'.**

**2. I also logout user if he is inactive for 30 minutes.**

I want to perform following actions on browser tab close,

**1. destroy session**

**2. update DB field logged_in as 0.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While user login i update DB field logged_in as 1.So, if same user login again i check this field (logged_in) and if its 1 then throw 'user already connected'.

You should compare IPs and session ID (`Yii::app()->getSession()->getSessionId()`) when the user tries to log in.

If the new login has a different session ID and/or IP, they should throw an error (per your request) though I suggest avoiding frustration for the user forgetting to log out and having to wait 30 minutes, and just override the old session. So if the user is logging in from a different location on the same timespan, you can overwrite the session id and ip address, and the old session would automatically be logged out.

So, you should have these fields in the DB for the user:

```
ip_address       | session_id          | last_active
```

You should keep the `last_active` field updated for the comparison to be accurate.

> I also logout user if he is inactive for 30 minutes.

Whenever the user tries to log in, or enters a page (and you should re-authenticate anyway):
- if the user has been active in the last 30 minutes, and the other information matches, this is the current session and login is null (can be disregarded and continue regularly).
- if the user has been inactive in 30 minutes or more, this new login should be written over the old information. So, new ip address and session id.
- if the user has been active but the information is different, throw an error (like I said though, I would avoid doing that).

You can have the session cookie expire after 30 minutes so a new session id will be generated if they are inactive.
On every page enter, if the user is logged in, overwrite the cookie and it will give it a new expiry date.
If it's been over 30 minutes since last activity, the user will get a new session id automatically, thus nullifying the last session and login, and forcing them to log in again.

> destroy session

Covered in the last point.

Comment: on tab close how to update db field logged_in to 0 ?

Comment: Nice solution. I agree. Triggering event on close tab is not a good solution and your approach is much better.

Comment: @AyyanarG i updated the answer to be more descriptive - i think you should avoid that idea, you never know if someone disabled JS, and it's very easy to override it manually on the client side. keep this on the server side (you can only trigger things on tab close through the server side)

Comment: @ChenAsraf After close of yii application, php code not running to set this logged_in field value to 0

Comment: look at what i wrote - you don't need the logged_in field at all. also i mistyped on the previous comment, you can only trigger things on tab close through the client** side

Comment: Do you have any suggestion about tab close events ?

Comment: my suggestion is to avoid them. you can have cookies with no expiry which means they automatically expire when the browser closes, this is as close as you're gonna get but i suggest using my answer as failsafe